# Safari Tabs like Firefox / Chrome

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, safari

Two things I miss from Firefox and Chrome when using Safari on Mac are the Command + Option + Arrows, that are replaced by Control + Tab or Command + Shift + Arrows, and specially the Command + #number, which will invoke bookmarks instead of tabs.

So I want to gather up ideas here on how to fix this. I've already found some on google, but I wish they were simpler - there could be a way to automate the setup.

edit: And that it wouldn't need a background app runnning.

Comment: Plus, there's one big consideration: the biggest reason why I even consider using Safari is for saving battery.

So it's important that there's no significant increase in processor usage or memory for any kind of patch - the more native the fix is, the better.

Comment: Why would moving to Safari save battery life? You might try the Chrome Beta for Mac. It's definitely better than Firefox for Mac in terms of performance/possible battery drain.

Comment: Well, I'm saying just after trying it. Safari seems to use less processor, and definitely less battery on regular use. It's just a matter to keep an eye on the percentage over time. I am using Chrome most times when AC plugged, and Firefox for internet banking mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disclaimer

Actually, there is generic answer from @donut -- thanks for this contribution! However, it wasn't clear from me when I met it. Thus, let me to concrete it exactly for <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> as it was asked initially.

### Solution for using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> in Safari

1. Go to *System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > App Shortcuts*
2. Click "+" button
3. Chose Safari within *Application* list
4. Type **Show Next Tab** for *Menu Title*
5. For *Keyboard Shortcut* press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>
6. Do the same for **Show Previous Tab**

[image: Should look like this]

### Solution for using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>1, 2, 3...</kbd> in Safari

1. Go to menu *Safari > Preferences > Tabs*
2. Check option *Use ⌘-1 through ⌘-9 to switch tabs*

[image: The red one]

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What you mean in the whole "Safari Specifics" section?

Comment: @cregox, thanks for a feedback! I've just checked -- it doesn't reproduce anymore. So, I'll remove this section.

Comment: nice job, and good update. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just as reference, and as a half-answer, following I'll summarize the options I've found. They came from two similar approaches, one from [justinblanton.com](http://justinblanton.com/2009/02/go-to-safari-tab-with-keyboard) and another from [pugio.net](http://pugio.net/2009/05/switching-tabs-safari-4-shortcuts-like-firefox.html).

Summing up, they both use [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) and this applescript:

```
try
    tell front window of application "Safari" to set current tab to tab 1
on error
    tell front window of application "Safari" to set current tab to last tab
end try
```

You'd have to save 9 files of this in **`~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Safari`**, and give them all shortcuts in FastScript.

In my case, the 9th one in my case have just the "last tab" 1 line and no "try", and I got the [SafariTabs.zip](http://pugio.net/SafariTabs.zip) file from **pugio** and put it on root scripts, in **`/Library/Scripts/Applications`**, rather than generating them and putting under Users.

***To re-enforce:*** I don't like this answer because it uses third-party backgrounded application. I wish a way to tweak my system, could be using the same application, but not needing more stuff running on my machine in the background.

Comment: As an aside: the downvote was not mine, but I assume the downvoter did not like *just* the links. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers (+1 to undo the non-commented downvote, as you're quite busy on your first days here.)

Comment: Thanks again, Arjan. I've got a lot of downvotes (6 within an hour, maybe less) out of nowhere, but that's fine. I just wish to know why. I haven't even read your link yet but I already agree I shouldn't have put just the links. At very least, a brief summary and actually writing the guides to the answer while linking to the source. I was hoping this wouldn't be an issue here given the context - it's not really the answer and I read somewhere it's encouraged to give the answer to own question rather than writing the answer ON the question. Anyways, still learning about this. ;)

Comment: If you put these scripts in the "Safari Scripts" folder, can you then assign keystrokes to them, and avoid FastScripts?

Comment: @Josh I thought of something like that (trying to assign keystrokes to the scripts within OSX) but I haven't even tried it. I figured the scripts would need to appear in Safari menus somehow... But I didn't know about Safari Scripts folder. I'll check it out now, thanks! ;)

Comment: @Cawas: I just tried it and sadly, it doesn't work. (For reference you can enable the AppleScript menu via /Applications/AppleScript/AppleScript Utility)

Comment: @Josh I have no such "AppleScript Utility" and I'm still unable to find the Safari Scripts folder supposed location, but since you've already say it doesn't work, I'll go back to my sorrow. :P One thing that might work, tho: SIMBL

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to override tab switching shortcut keys with the Keyboard Shortcuts override in the Keyboard & Mouse preference pane.

So... *Top-left Apple Icon* > *System Preferences* > *Keyboard & Mouse* > *Keyboard Shortcuts* > *+* button. Follow the directions there.

Comment: Ok, that actually works wonders for Next and Previous Tabs - and I really overlooked it.
But what about numbering?

Comment: Except I wish to replace Cmd + Shift + Arrows rather than replacint Ctrl + Tab. And numbering was the most important one, since there's no similar functionality built-in. So this didn't help much in the end. :P

Comment: I actually am using a mix of this, SIMBL and FastScripts (as mentioned in my answer). But since this was the main solution, I'll just take it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For tab switching, you can use [SafariStand](http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html), which has a nice feature for it : use `,` or `.`

For direct access to tabs, you can use [Saft](http://haoli.dnsalias.com/Saft/index.html), which allows you to directly access tabs with `Ctrl-#number`.

Both plugins have useful features

Comment: That seems like a lot of things to install for such small improvements. I'm already not happy with having to install FastScripts for actually using Command + #number. But this may work for some people.

Answer (score 0):

While I realize this post is quite old, I've found another solution that is a bit easier to implement, and built into a fairly common/awesome piece of Mac software, Alfred.

Using Alfred workflows from "MacGeeky" [posted here](http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/2580-browsertabs-chromesafari-close-tabs-to-the-leftright-switch-between-tabs-with-keyboard/#entry16343), you can regain direct numbered tab access in Safari via whatever hotkey you define (in my case, I like the Google Chrome implementation as well and use Command-1, Command-2, etc.).

Comment: this seems like a good idea only for who already uses [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/), or maybe intend to.